# Crear una barra de búsqueda en la base de datos MongoDB con Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, listview

Tengo una barra de búsqueda en la que quiero buscar perfumes en una base de datos MongoDB. Intenté de dos maneras pero nunca funciona.

Aqui esta el HTML template para ambos:

`search_similar.html`:

```html
  <div class="recommendations">
    <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
      <div class="form">
        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
          <input type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" />
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" action = "/predict" method="POST">
          <input type="text" placeholder="perfume name"/> <!-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRODv6UTXpM&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge -->
          <input type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" />
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
```

`views.py`:

```
import pymongo
import todo.config as config
from django.db.models import Q


username = config.username
password = config.password

...

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        perfume_list = list(collection.find({'q0.Results.0.Name': {"$regex" : query}}, {'item_name': 1, 'brand': 1, 'gender': 1,
                                                                         'note': 1, 'tags': 1, 'theme': 1, '_id': 0}))

        print("perfume_list: ", perfume_list)
        return perfume_list
```

Pero `perfume_list` quede desesperadamente vacío.

Pero incluso en MongoDB Atlas, tengo problemas para buscar en diccionarios anidados. en efecto la consulta en la imagen que vemos por debajo no da el resultado que podemos ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Anexo: `urls.py` para hacer un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible

`urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [

    ...

    # similar
    path('similar', views.search_similar, name='similar'),
    path('similar_results', views.SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results')

]
```